# AngularJS, Redirect user to correct page after login

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

My login page of website is made in AngularJS and rest is written in Laravel
So I am trying to find out a way to implement the following feature for my website in AngularJS.
When user copies a URL from my website, logs out of the session.Subsequently he copy pastes the URL in the browser. It should redirect him to the page he copy pasted after login.
At the moment, the behavior is when you copy paste a URL it redirects to login, After login, it redirects to dashboard and not the specific page which was pasted in the browser.
Any Ideas in how this can be implemented in Angular at the login page?
Thanks
All the help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be in the interceptor or whatever you have that is redirecting them to the login page, you need to grab the URL and tack it on as a parameter when you redirect to login. Something like '/login?redirect=/other/page'. Then in your login controller you can redirect to that page if the redirect parameter is in the URL, otherwise goto dashboard.